# how to pull, push with remote branch

Tags: python, git, git-push, git-pull, gitpython

I'm trying to automate a change process which currently creates source code that gets manually pushed to Git. I'm trying to wrap that code using [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython):

```
from git import *

# create the local repo
repo = Repo.init("/tmp/test/repo", bare=True)
assert repo.bare == True

# check status of active branch
repo.is_dirty()

# clone the remote repo
remote_repo = repo.clone("http://user:pass@git/repo.git")

# compile source code into repository
# ... 

# track untracked files
repo.untracked_files

# commit changes locally
repo.commit("commit changes")

# push changes to master
remote_repo.push()
```

When I try running this, I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "git_test2.py", line 33, in
>
> repo.commit("commit changes")
>
> BadObject: 636f6d6d6974206368616e676573

The script is able to pull the remote repository, but fails on commit. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Can you paste a traceback that shows *where* in that code the error is raised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the functions you are using may not work the way you expect them to.  Generally, `Repo` methods are *not* the equivalent of the `git` sub-command with the same name.

- [`Repo.commit` does not *create* a commit but *retrieve* an existing commit.](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.2/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.commit)  Since there is not commit named “commit changes” in the repository, an exception is raised.
- [`Repo.clone` creates a clone of *this* repository](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.2/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.clone) in a directory called `http:` inside the repository's directory structure which is most probably not what you want.

If you are trying to clone a remote repository, this can be achieved in a single line:

```
repo = Repo.clone_from("http://user:pass@git/repo.git", "/tmp/test/repo")
```

See the [API Reference](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.2/reference.html) for more information on how to use GitPython.

Answer (score 1):

You can't commit against a bare repository. You can only push/pull to them.  By parallel think about how you would do this locally. Try cloning a bare repo and doing the actions, they won't work.

I'm not intimately familiar with the pythonic git bindings, but would imagine that you would need to clone a  working repository, optionally checkout a given branch instead of master, do your work, call git add against just that stuff, and then commit.

Also, repo.untracked_files is a no op that simply lists them, it doesn't add them.

Honestly it looks like you blindly copy pasted from https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html without actually reading what it had to say.

you'll need to manipulate the Index Object for example

```
index = repo.index
for ( path, stage ), entry in index.entries.iteritems: pass
index.add(['SOMEFILE'])
new_commit = index.commit("YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE")
#do somethign with new commit
```

Another example I found

```
import git
repo = git.Repo( '/home/me/repodir' )
print repo.git.status()
# checkout and track a remote branch
print repo.git.checkout( 'origin/somebranch', b='somebranch' )
# add a file
print repo.git.add( 'somefile' )
# commit
print repo.git.commit( m='my commit message' )
# now we are one commit ahead
print repo.git.status()
# now push
```

Comment: Ah, in retrospect would a pull be more appropriate over a clone, followed by making changes, committing and pushing?

Comment: No, you need to clone but you shouldn't use a bare repository. also the rest of your usage is bogus see my update

Comment: you can use gitpython on a bare repos. you can create commits on them too, but only to the `HEAD` branch.